# Fetch MySQLi with custom database (aka, column names for array keys)

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote a website using Google App Engine intended for the 'Datastore' database but now the website is already complete and because of Google's resources limit the website goes down too frequently (and I don't have any money to spend on it, even if I did I wouldn't :/)

**Question:**

When ever I fetch a table, I want to simply return it like this:

- Each row is in it's own array to make it easy to iterate through
- Instead of the standard number, each key would be the name of column is from

**Problem:**

No matter if I use `fetch_all`, `fetch_assoc`, or `fetch_object`I never get anything that looks like what I am trying to get.

I am pretty bad with iterations and for loops so I couldn't figure how to do it manually.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` performs exactly that, however using a `mysqli` resource, only 1 row is returned at a time, which is why you see a lot of result loops. An easy line to do this is: `$result = array(); while($result[] = $mysqli_con->mysqli_fetch_assoc());`

Comment: Thanks man, this does exactly what I want. Didn't realize it was that easy :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to build an associative array of database rows with `mysqli_*` is to do this:

```
$mysqli_query = mysqli_query($db_link, "SELECT * FROM tablename");
$result = array();
while($result[] = $mysqli_query->mysqli_fetch_assoc());
```

and `$result` will hold the array you want